# My Data is Not Stored in Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, android-volley

I am making a simple register app where user sign up and data store in the My Mydatabase like usename, name, age, passsword

I already created database table in phpMyAdmin and I uploaded Register.php file into my server I check Register.php file their is no error it works great (I use postman app that act as app to send sign up details to the server it actually work my database is storing the values send by the postman app but when I use android app and sign up data is not storing in my database)

They should be some mistake in my code but error is not showing I take entire day to solve the problem not still not found.

I am referring to this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7Z4GVFaT4A&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka&index=4

I am using volley networking library in my gradle file

Here Register Activity where user enter username, name, age, password is store and send back to another activity to send server

It is linked with xml file whre user can sign up

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username , name , pass , age;
    Button r_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    username  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_et);
    name  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_et);
    pass  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass_et);
    age  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age_et);
    r_button =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_button);


    r_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             String usname = username.getText().toString();
             String nam   = name.getText().toString();
             String password = pass.getText().toString();
             int ages = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());


            Response.Listener<String> responselistner = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success)
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                          //after successfull sign up it redirect to login page 

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Registration failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("retry",null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(nam, usname,ages,password , responselistner);
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            requestQueue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Here is my class RegisterRequest

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL ="http://fgeeges.esy.es/Register.php";


private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name , String username , int age , String password , Response.Listener<String> listener)
{
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL , listener ,null);
         params = new HashMap<>();
         params.put("name ",name);
         params.put("username",username);
         params.put("age" ,age+"");
         params.put("password",password);


}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return params;
}
```

in the RegisterRequest Class.

Comment: where should i add this and why i add can you give me reasone

Comment: Could you add a small explanation about what this does

Comment: its is sign up where user can enter name username age password and this detail is store in database i also provide the link of the video

Comment: Volley must be using the getParams method of the StringRequest Class. And if you not override that method then it will not return params to the volley. So volley will not be able to fetch your data in params and thus will send the default params to the server.

 See here https://android.googlesource.com/.../volley/Request.java...
getParams() method return null.